# A unique event needed when the user just signed in

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to do some logic at the moment when the user just signed in. Remember its last connection date for the current session, then update the last connection date to `Now`.

The problem is that **the event I need should occur only once** after the user signs in. If it occurs several times, the *real* "last connection date" will be overwritten with the actual date, not ok....

What I can use to do it?

I use a AzureAD authentication. I use an event `OnValidatePrincipal`, but this one occurs multiple times...

Is there a event that fits better to this situation?

Bellow my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
// [...]
services
.AddDistributedMemoryCache()
.AddSession(options =>
{   // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
    options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
})
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnSignedIn = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnSignedIn, context=" + context);
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        },
        OnValidatePrincipal = async context =>
        {
            var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
            if (user.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var mySingletonUser = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUser>();
                var repository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITableRepositories>();
                var lastConnectedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var userId = user.Name;
                var myUser = await repository.GetAsync<Connection>(userId);
                context.HttpContext.Session.SetString(UserController.SessionKeyFormerConnetion, myUser.LastConnectedOn.ToLongDateString());

                Claim isAdminClaim = new Claim("IsAdmin", myUser.IsAdmin.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean);
                user.AddClaim(isAdminClaim);

                myUser.LastConnectedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var updatedUser = repository.InsertOrMergeAsync(new List<Connection> { myUser });
                // update user from DB to display on the GUI
                UpdateMySingletonUser(context.HttpContext.RequestServices, myUser);
```

Bellow is the debug log of the application, when a user signs out then signs in back again:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/Account/SignOut  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/Account/SignOut  
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Warning: Accessing expired session, Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Warning: Accessing expired session, Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignOut (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignOut (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignOutResult: Information: Executing SignOutResult with authentication schemes (Cookies, OpenIdConnect).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignOutResult: Information: Executing SignOutResult with authentication schemes (Cookies, OpenIdConnect).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignOut (MyApp) in 903.6182ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignOut (MyApp) in 903.6182ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Information: Session started; Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy, Id:yyyy-uuu-bbb-zzz
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Information: Session started; Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy, Id:yyyy-uuu-bbb-zzz
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 1025.876ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 1025.876ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/signout-callback-oidc?state=xxx-yyy  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/signout-callback-oidc?state=xxx-yyy  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 21.9454ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 21.9454ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/Account/SignedOut  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/Account/SignedOut  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed for user: (null).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed for user: (null).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult: Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult: Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignedOut (MyApp) in 55.726ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignedOut (MyApp) in 55.726ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 87.2328ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 87.2328ms 302 
The thread 0x299c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3b90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2714 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:23404/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1878
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:23404/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1878
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 416.2449ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 416.2449ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/Account/SignedOut  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/Account/SignedOut  
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Warning: Accessing expired session, Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Warning: Accessing expired session, Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignedOut (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignedOut (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult: Information: Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult: Information: Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignedOut (MyApp) in 14.6064ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.SignedOut (MyApp) in 14.6064ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Information: Session started; Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy, Id:yyyy-uuu-bbb
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession: Information: Session started; Key:xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy, Id:yyyy-uuu-bbb
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 89.5447ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 89.5447ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/  
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
>>> Index HomeController, xuser = {MyApp.Data.Connection}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor: Information: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor: Information: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyApp) in 1264.8062ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyApp) in 1264.8062ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 1340.4051ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 1340.4051ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Theme  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Theme  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Progress  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Relevance  
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Progress  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Record  
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Record  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:23404/api/Relevance  
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
>>> OnValidatePrincipal
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.ThemeController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
>>> New User updated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.ThemeController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.ProgressController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.ProgressController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.RelevanceController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Controllers.RelevanceController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Api.Controllers.RecordController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method MyApp.Api.Controllers.RecordController.Get (MyApp) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.ThemeController.Get (MyApp) in 167.0241ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.ThemeController.Get (MyApp) in 167.0241ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 297.0212ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 297.0212ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.ProgressController.Get (MyApp) in 129.5805ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.ProgressController.Get (MyApp) in 129.5805ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 314.6259ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 314.6259ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.RelevanceController.Get (MyApp) in 293.8995ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.RelevanceController.Get (MyApp) in 293.8995ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 491.3647ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 491.3647ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Api.Controllers.RecordController.Get (MyApp) in 481.3165ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyApp.Api.Controllers.RecordController.Get (MyApp) in 481.3165ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 675.4075ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 675.4075ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
The thread 0x4318 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The most probable I need to catch the moment when it logs (twice, unfortunately :( )

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myUser@myOrg.net.
```

what event does correspond to that log?